What is $A \times B$ if $A= \varnothing$ but B is a finite/infinite set?
I've read that $A \times B = \varnothing$ if both sets are equal to $\varnothing$ but what about if one is $\varnothing$ but the other is finite or infinite?
Can it be like: suppose A =  and B={1,2} and ×= { (,1), (,2) } ?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937245/why-is-the-cartesian-product-of-a-and-varnothing-empty and many others.

Let $A = \varnothing$, $B$ be a (finite or infinite) set.
Then
$$ A \times B = \{ (x, y) | x \in A \land y \in B \} $$
$$ = \varnothing $$
The last equality is due to the fact that $\nexists a: a \in A$.
You can also prove that it is empty by contradiction: assume $\exists (x, y) : x \in A \land y \in B$.
That would imply $\exists a: a \in A$ which directly contradicts $
\nexists a: a \in A$

Please don't answer no-effort and duplicate questions. See here. Elementary and trivial set theory questions are duplicates in 99,99% of the time. Instead of writing an answer you are encouraged to find appropriate duplicates and close the question. In this case, a duplicate has already been identified in the comments (but there are more candidates as well).

The question is not duplicate as math.stackexchange.com/q/2438191/42969 asks a proof for the case of  both sets being equal to . But I am asking something else ( as I have mentioned in the details), that what if only one is =  @MartinBrandenburg

But why can't it be like:
suppose A =  and B={1,2} and ×= { (,1), (,2) }

Although the other post may be about $\emptyset\times \emptyset$ rather then $\emptyset\times A$ the reasoning that both are empty is exactly the same.  I'm pretty sure elsewhere there is a duplicate that does consider $\emptyset \times A; A \ne \emptyset$ even if that one didn't.

But I guess you shouldn't make such claims unless you actually find the duplicate.. @fleablood. Also I have gone through that page but I don't think I have found my answer... so what am I to do in that case?

I confess I can't EVER find ANYTHING I search for in the search function because a post in math with the same idea can use utterly different symbols or words than I might think the would, and I get very irritated by the prevailing attitude here the search for duplicates and making sure your question has not been asked it the simplest easiest thing in the world.  But that said the page you found does deal with $A\times B = \emptyset$ if and only if either $A$ or $B$ (not nescessarily both be at least one) is empty. So that does cover your question. If you don't think it does...

... at this point it is up to you to specify just where you get confused.

I completely relate with you. But also everytime I post a question there are always a dozen people claiming it to be a duplicate when it clearly isn't and have the audacity to say the question isn't well researched/no effort when in-fact they haven't read or understood the question properly @MartinBrandenburg . As to where exactly I have a problem, I think we were already discussing it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Of course it's a duplicate. I have entered "Cartesian product empty set" into the search input and immediately found several duplicates such as this one. And yes of course you should not search with variable names. By the way, this search took me 10 seconds. How long does it take to write an answer?

Regarding your guess, you are confusing $\emptyset$ and ${\emptyset}$. Generally speaking, as a beginner you need to learn to work with the definitions instead of just guessing.
